# How to create a cms block with existing block content using widget in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, cms-block, widget

Is it possible in Magento 2 to create a new cms block(using widget) with content of an existing block, and admin can change the images, links and text of new block????

Actually, I need a template(widget), and it should be called in different pages. For different pages, I need to change the template's images, text and links. For example, I have a cms block for showing these images on homepage

[image]

Now, I need the same block for some other page, but I need options to change images(using image uploader), texts and links... Any help will be appreciated... Thanks

Comment: Can you please explain/elaborate  ?

Comment: @Arun, I have edited my question. Please check...

Comment: is the content dynamic or static ?

Comment: content is dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

You can call a phtml template in you static block and write you logic in the template file

Create a block with content

```
{{block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::html/dynamic-images.phtml"}}
```

then create a template file `dynamic-images.phtml` under `\app\design\frontend\<Vendor>\<Theme_Name>\Magento_Theme\templates\html`

and write you dynamic code in `dynamic-images.phtml`.

don't forget to clear cache (`php bin/magento cache:clean`) every time you make changes to `dynamic-images.phtml`.

I hope you know how to create a widget.